# I have a counter which has to be triggered only once when the page scrolls to certain element in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, counter

I have a counter on a certain part of the page which has to be triggered only once when the scroll reaches that element. I can see various solutions in jQuery but I'm looking for the answer in terms of react or pure javascript.

I implemented it using states and react hooks but I see some instability all the time triggering more than once even if I preserve the state and use conditional statements. I'm not sure where I was going wrong.

Here is the react class component(I switched to class from function due to continuous warning while using useEffect)

**Update:** I found a working solution as below. If there's any other better method to do this please let me know.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

export default function DataCounter({ count, title }) {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(false);

  const increment = useCallback(() => {
    const counter = (length = 2000) => {
      setNumber(0);
      let n = count;
      let start = Date.now();
      let end = start + length;
      let interval = length / n;
      const sInt = setInterval(() => {
        let time = Date.now();
        if (time < end) {
          let count = Math.floor((time - start) / interval);
          setNumber(count);
        } else {
          setNumber(n);
          clearInterval(sInt);
        }
      }, interval);
    };

    counter();
  }, [count]);

  document.addEventListener("scroll", async () => {
    const element = await document.getElementById("data");
    const elementPosition = await element.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    if (window.pageYOffset > elementPosition) setTrigger(true);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (trigger) {
      increment();
    }
  }, [trigger, increment]);

  return (
    <div className="counter">
      <div className="counter-number">{number}</div>
      <p className="counter-title">{title}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Initial version:**

```
import React from "react";

export default class Counter extends React.Component {
   state = {
    number: 0,
    loaded: false
  };

  increment(n, length = 2000){
    this.setState({ number: 0 });

    let start = Date.now();
    let end = start + length;
    let interval = length / n;
    const sInt = setInterval(() => {
      let time = Date.now();
      if (time < end) {
        let count = Math.floor((time - start) / interval);
        this.setState({ number: count });
      } else {
        this.setState({ number: n });
 
        clearInterval(sInt);
      }
    }, interval);
  };

  async handleScroll() {
    const element = await document.getElementById("data");
    const elementPosition = await element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

    if (window.pageYOffset > elementPosition) {
      if(!this.state.loaded) {
        this.increment(100);
        this.setState({ loaded: true });
      }
      return;
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="counter">
        <div className="counter-number">{this.state.number}</div>
        <p className="counter-title">{this.props.title}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand this: *I have a counter on a certain part of the page which has to be triggered only once when the scroll reaches that element*, but what does your `increment` function do exactly?

Comment: It increments the number from 0 to 100 in 2 seconds, in this case, I hardcoded the value to 100. Whenever I reach a particular element on the page, I want to trigger this `increment`

Comment: Can you please make your functional component sulotion separated from your original code? The overwrite makes my answer look confusing

Comment: Your answer is right. What I was missing was `this`. Also, I added `async`  to wait for the element to get loaded because scrolling can be done before a component gets fully loaded. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you declared your class method in a wrong way. Since you are using the ES6 way to declare the state (you are not using a constructor), so you have to declare your class method in ES6 way as well. Such as,

```
increment = (n, length = 2000) => {
   // so you can access *this* variable in this scope
   ...
}
```

And this goes the same for `handleScroll` method. If you want to declare a helper method like what you did in your code:

```
increment(n, length = 2000){
  ...
}
```

**Then you need to declare a constructor and bind `this` in the constructor.** You can find the reference [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance).

Secondly, it is absolutely unnecessary to have `handleScroll` as an async function. There is no promise being returned in this method.

Last but not the least, always remember to remove the scroll listener in `componentWillUnmount`, so you won't have a stack of listeners listening to windows scroll event when the user switches among routes or the component gets mounted again.

Here is [a working example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-to-the-element-and-trigger-counter-8g770?file=/src/Counter.js:658-670).

Answer (score 1):

I found a problem with your code

You are registering 'scroll' event listener inside the body of the function component. This is why the scroll event is triggered multiple times.

Because every rendering of the function component will add one additional scroll event to the DOM

The correct way to register and cleanup any DOM event is inside the 'useEffect' react hook like this

```
const handleScrollEvent = async () => {
    const element = await document.getElementById("data");
    const elementPosition = await element.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    if (window.pageYOffset > elementPosition) setTrigger(true);
}

const registerEvent = () => {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", handleScrollEvent);
}

const unRegisterEvent = () => {
    document.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScrollEvent);
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (trigger) {
        increment();
    }

    //Register the event inside useEffect after the component mounts
    registerEvent();

    //Cleanup the registered event once the component is unmounted from 
    //the DOM
    return unRegisterEvent;

}, [trigger, increment]);
```

Comment: I've a question here. Whenever I add any functions to `useEffect` that need to be called after the component gets mounted, I keep seeing warnings always, to add the function to the dependency list, maybe that was one reason why I kept the event listener outside the `useEffect`. And if I add the function to the dependency list, one more warning is shown to add the function inside `useCallback`. So what's the solution to this, even for this solution it shows a warning(red underlines) for the two added functions inside the `useEffect`.

Comment: @hashBender, we can ignore the warnings in this case. It is desirable only to add state values of a component in the dependencies list. Adding local variables may cause unexpected behavior like infinite re-rendering

Comment: Please refer for more information about the dependencies list https://medium.com/better-programming/understanding-the-useeffect-dependency-array-2913da504c44

Comment: In above link, there is a topic "What Is a Dependency Array?". It will help you understand